# How should I organize skills in my resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, student

I have the following **Skills:**
HTML - CSS - Bootstrap - Javascript - JQuery
Angular2+
Java - Spring MVC - Spring Boot - JEE
MongoDB - SQL Databases
REST - GraphQL
PHP - Symfony
C++
Git - Jenkins

What's the best way to list them all in my resume ? should i organize them by category ? or by expert ? Or just list them randomly ?
And should i list them all ?

Answer (score 1):

I like to see them organized by category. Otherwise, it's alphabet soup to a lay reader.